# Difference between Ctrl+Refresh and Ctrl+Shift+Refresh?

Tags: http, cache

I understand that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Refresh fetches fresh content from browser without reading the cache. Then what is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Refresh for?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Refresh request header are like this:

```
Cache-Control : max-age=0
```

for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Refresh

```
Pragma : no-cache <br>
Cache-Control : no-cache
```

What is the real difference?

Comment: What browser are you using? Ctrl+Shift+F5 does nothing in both Firefox 3.5 or IE 6.

Comment: I always thought CTRL+SHIFT+REFRESH was a gimmick programmers told their clients...

Comment: @user2980 well you're wrong :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are identical to the browser on the local machine. The headers you mentioned are the only difference.

The Ctrl+Refresh header means that any caching servers along the way should return a fresh copy of the page.

The Ctrl+Shift+Refresh headers mean that any caching servers along the way should return a fresh copy of the page, and should also not cache the page for any future requests. In other words, the next time the page is requested, it should either use a previous cache of the page or request a fresh copy, but should not use this one.

Pragma: no-cache is the HTTP 1.0 version of Cache-Control: no-cache. There is no HTTP 1.0 equivalent to Cache-Control: max-age=0.

RFC2616 section 14 subsection 9 has relevant information: [w3c.org: RFC2616 sec 14.9.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

There is another difference, and a big one at that.

When you hit Ctrl+Refresh, for every cached object that has a `Last-Modified` or `ETag` header, the browser will issue a request with an `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` header. The server may then choose to respond with a `304 Not Modified`, without re-sending any data (assuming the data is, in fact, not modified).

When you hit Ctrl+Shift+Refresh, the browser won't issue such conditional `If-*` headers, leaving the server no option but to send the data again.